# Will Cloud Endpoints Frameworks support Java11 in the future?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, java-11, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm thinking about migrating my App Engine Project to Java11. Will Cloud Endpoints Frameworks eventually support Java11 or do I need to switch to a different framework?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know if the support will be added, is by opening an issue on the [github page](https://github.com/cloudendpoints) of Cloud Endpoints Framework

Google recently launched a new service called [API gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway), this is like a new version of Cloud Endpoints both works by using OpenAPI v2 and can work as a replacement for **Cloud Endpoints Framework**, I deployed a hello world application in App engine standrad using Java 11 and works as is expected, please check the [API Gateway+App Engine quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-app-engine) to know how to deploy an API Gateway service for your App Engine service

Technically API gateway will be use a service account to authenticate all incoming requests by using [Cloud IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap), for example:

[request] --> [API gateway] --[request+ auth w/service account]-->[Cloud IAP] --> [App Engine]

Comment: I think you are mixing up Cloud Endpoints and the Cloud Endpoints Framework.         
   **Cloud Endpoints Framework** - *"Endpoints Frameworks is a web framework for the App Engine standard Python 2.7 and Java 8 runtime environments. Cloud Endpoints Frameworks provides the tools and libraries that allow you to generate REST APIs and client libraries for your application."*                 **Cloud Endpoints**- *"Endpoints is an API management system that helps you secure, monitor, analyze, and set quotas on your APIs using the same infrastructure Google uses for its own APIs."*

Comment: @Hugo I think that the best way to know if the support will be added, is by opening an issue on the [github page](https://github.com/cloudendpoints) of Cloud Endpoints Framework

Comment: The github project seems to be dead.